# Experience with LinuxGSM

Tags: pi-4, ubuntu

I'm looking to buy a Raspberry Pi 4B (4GB) do run a Ubuntu 19.10 server from. I read that the x64 version is supported so I was wondering if the following is still an issue.

> **Will LinuxGSM run on Raspberry PI?**
>
> Short answer: No.
> Raspberry PI uses ARM architecture whereas all the game servers will only run on x86 compatible architectures such as 32-bit and 64-bit versions of distros. Raspberry PI is not compatible with x86.

[Source](https://docs.linuxgsm.com/support/faq)

But if the new Raspberry Pi support x64 then this would mean that it could practically run LinuxGSM, am I right?

Interested in your thoughts.

Jim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is unchanged.  All Pis use an ARM architecture which is incompatible with the Intel 86 or AMD 64 architectures.

I think you are getting confused by the ARM processor itself being 64 bit and the availability now of 64 bit operating systems for the Pi.

Comment: I guess I'm better off using a small AMD/Intel based NUC as a server then. It will run Ubuntu without a problem and it will be fully 64-bit compatible. Thanks for clearing the air!